# How to select rows while in edit mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is editable. I am commiting changes via:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

While in edit mode, I would like the user to be able to select a row, which will push a new view. I am not sure how to do this. I suspect it will be in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But how can I determine if the user is in edit mode or not?

UPDATE:
Edit Mode is toggled via:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To allow selection during editing you need to set the `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property of `UITableView` to YES. Then it will call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` message. You can find more information about that property here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelectionDuringEditing

Then, you can see if the user is in edit mode by running code like the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView.editing == YES) {
        // Table view is editing - run code here
    }
}
```

Comment: With iOS 9, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called while in edit mode even with allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES.  Instead, you can implement willSelectRowAtIndexPath-- which will get called if you also set allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES.

Comment: @lifjoy, I'm developing on IOS 9.2, didSelectRowAtIndexPath solution is still works through allowsSelectionDuringEditing.

Comment: @Jerry Chen: that's curious.  No matter what I did, didSelectRowAtIndexPath was not working for me when the table was in Edit mode.

Comment: @Jerry Chen: found the answer.  didSelectRowAtIndexPath works while editing when both allowsSelectionDuringEditing and allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing are YES.