# Setting edit mode of uitableview disables row selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview, edit, mode

When I set the edit mode of my uitableview by using

```
[listTableView setEditing:YES];
```

I am not able to select the table rows anymore. It does not take the control to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

When I comment the above line, it is ok.

Any idea why? I need the editing and selection features.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? Editing mode is for adding/deleting, etc. the cells, so you'd generally enter edit mode for such operations and then leave edit mode for "normal" selection operations.

Comment: good point, thanks. I coded the setEditing in viewDidLoad, so it was in edit mode all the time. Removed that and allocated a button and action for setting and removing edit mode and it works, thanks!

Comment: Cool. I'll add an answer for the sake of prosperity. :-)

Comment: Please check at the question at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278264/how-to-select-rows-while-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 15):

listTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;